# Find a non-negative, non zero function in a specific domain that $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0.$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I need an integrable function with the domain $[a,b]$, and the function is non-negative, and it is not the zero function in that domain, and $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=0.$ I couldn't find any function like that!!!!

Comment: Riemann integrable?

Comment: Check out [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

Comment: Indedd, any function such that its set of discontinuities has measure zero is Riemann integrable, thus you can consider the following function:$$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}1,\textrm{ if x=0},\\0,\textrm{ if x$\neq$0}\end{matrix}\right.$$ Such function is integrable, with integral equal zero and satisfies your conditions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hints

- $f$ doesn't have to be continuous
- even though $f$ isn't the zero function, it can be zero at some (or even *many*) points

Comment: can such function be Riemann integrable?

Comment: @DiegoMath Most certainly.

Answer (score 2):

If a non-negative continuous function $f$ is non-zero at some $x_0 \in [a,b]$, then you can find a neighborhood $B_{\epsilon}(x_0)\cap[a,b]$ around $x_0$ where $f$ is positive. This means that $\int_a^b f d(x) > 0$. So, no continuous function can satisfy your condition.

However, you can create as many discontinuous examples as you want by taking functions of the form:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}1,\textrm{ if x=}x_0,\\0,\textrm{ if x$\neq$}x_0\end{matrix}\right.$$